# Fix Ubuntu Minimal BASH-like line editing error

Tags: grub2, gnu

I have ubuntu installed on an external hard drive. I installed the grub on the main ssd in my laptop, as this was mentioned on a tutorial back when I installed ubuntu. I used to get this error, although I didn't think it was an error before. After entering exit it would go to the linux boot menu where I could select ubuntu or windows. Now when I enter exit it goes straight to windows, so i cannot boot into ubuntu anymore.

I booted from the bootable usb I made back when I installed it and ran boot repair from the try ubuntu option. That did not fix the issue either. Here is the link it gave me. http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QJMdrxkQwB/